# Can every Multilinear form be defined as a sequence of consecutive contractions?

Tags: tensor-products, tensors

I’m trying to understand tensors and tensor decomposition.

It occurred to me that every multilinear form is a chain of contractions, since the tensor contraction of an $(s;t)$ tensor leaves me with a $(s-1;t-1)$ tensor, then, for every $(k;0)$ tensor over the field $\mathbb{F}$:
$$\mathcal{T}^{i_0…i_k}\in V^{\otimes k}$$
And every sequence of contractions $\gamma_i:V^{\otimes i}\otimes V^*\rightarrow V^{\otimes i-1}$, I have:
$$(\gamma_k\cdots\gamma_1\circ\gamma_0)(\mathcal{T}^{i_0…i_k})\in \mathbb{F}$$
And so, the function $\hat{\gamma}=\gamma_k\cdots\gamma_1\circ\gamma_0$ can be defined as $\hat{\gamma}:V^k\rightarrow \mathbb{F}$, wich is precisely the definition of a multilinear form.
Is this argument correct?

Also, can it be used as a suficient proof of the multilinear form being a composition of series of contractions? If it isn’t sufficient, can it be proven?

**Edit**

It was pointed out in the section of coments that the definition of contraction as a function differs from what i thought it was. I corrected this error in the post’s notation.

Comment: Can you be more explicit in defining $\gamma_i$? It seems like you're trying to perform tensor contractions on $V^{\otimes k}$, something like $\sum_aT^{aabcde\cdots}$. If this is the case, then this is invalid: you can only pair upper and lower indices, or in other words contractions only happen on $V\otimes V^*$ (unless you have some sort of metric).

Comment: So a contraction can’t be a function?

Comment: Sure it can, but it's a function $V\otimes V^*\otimes X \to X$. There's a possibility I'm not understanding what you mean by "contraction", so I asked for you to define $\gamma_i$ explicitly. An example would be fine. I'm thinking what you might mean is an interior product $\gamma(T)(v_1, v_2, \dotsc) = T(v, v_1, v_2, \dotsc)$ for some fixed $v \in V$ or $V^*$ (depending on the type of $T$).

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for, but for any type $(r,s)$ tensor field $T$, the value $T(\theta^1,\ldots, \theta^r, v_1,\ldots, v_s)$ equals a compositions of contractions applied to the tensor $T\otimes \theta^1\otimes\cdots\otimes \theta^r\otimes v_1\otimes\cdots\otimes v_s$.

Comment: @IvoTerek, i think i do not understand your notation. A tensor field T assigns a tensor to each point on a topological space $\tau$. If $x\in \tau$, then $T(x)= \mathcal{T}$, where $\mathcal{T}$ is a tensor, right? So then how is $T(x)$ a contraction?

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff, yes. An interior product is the main idea i’ve got in my head of what a “contraction” could mean. Since the scalar product between two vectors $\vec{v}\cdot\vec{w}=\vec{v}\overline{w}$ must be a contraction (because of the vector transposing and stuff) and it is a map from a vector space $V:\rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ to the base field, then it should also be a multilinear form… so… since every tensor space $T$ is a vector space, the inner product of two tensors in $T$ is a multilinear form AND a contraction (or composition of them) at the same time?

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff as for the explicit examples of $\gamma_i$ i was thinking on the linear mappings from a matrix to the base field. Something like the multiplication of an $m\times n$ matrix $A$ by the $1\times m$ vector $v$ and the $n\times 1$ vector $w$. I this case, it would be something like: $(\gamma_w\circ\gamma_v)(A)=vAw=k$, where $k\in \mathbb{F}$

Comment: This is called currying. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying